# Not able to use Anaconda distribution after installation on Windows 10 Home (64-bit) - python36.dll missing

Tags: python, installation, anaconda

I'm trying to install Python via the Anaconda distribution on my laptop (Windows 10 Home, 64-bit, Intel i5 6200U). I downloaded the Anaconda3-5.3.0-Windows-x86_64.exe file from https://www.anaconda.com/download/ (3.7 version) , followed all the instructions as guided in the How-To document and sticked to all defaults (http://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/).

When I try to open for example a Jupyter Notebook, it says Kernel Error. By clicking on the error message, I receive this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1592, in _execute
    result = yield result
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 73, in post
    type=mtype))
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 79, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1141, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 92, in start_kernel_for_session
    self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 1133, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 326, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 160, in start_kernel
    super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
    km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 259, in start_kernel
    **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 204, in _launch_kernel
    return launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 128, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1155, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

**Update:** After the suggestion of @Surya Radhakrishnan, I typed in the conda console

```
conda install ipykernel
```

But now, I get this error message:

[image: Now I get this error message:]

I reinstalled Anaconda several times and tried different versions of it, but nothing helps. The Jupyther Notebook console shows this:

```
[I 03:16:46.306 NotebookApp] JupyterLab beta preview extension loaded from C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyterlab
[I 03:16:46.306 NotebookApp] JupyterLab application directory is C:\Users\Constantin\Anaconda3\share\jupyter\lab
[I 03:16:46.462 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: C:\Users\Constantin
[I 03:16:46.462 NotebookApp] 0 active kernels
[I 03:16:46.462 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 03:16:46.462 NotebookApp] http://localhost:8888/?token=cddf0b143d19105a2aae867580238ea9b4b9205530edc569
[I 03:16:46.462 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[C 03:16:46.462 NotebookApp]

    Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
    to login with a token:
        http://localhost:8888/?token=cddf0b143d19105a2aae867580238ea9b4b9205530edc569&token=cddf0b143d19105a2aae867580238ea9b4b9205530edc569
[I 03:16:46.681 NotebookApp] Accepting one-time-token-authenticated connection from ::1
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally  we get this error when we try to access jupyter notebook where ipykernel is not installed. Please check and install ipykernel if you don't have it.

```
conda install ipykernel
```

Comment: Its not working. No I get an error message: "The program can't start because python36.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix the problem". I reinstalled it already multiple times, but it does not help. Any ideas?